# MySQL WHERE clause not working after CSV import

Tags: mysql, database, csv

I have a problem with a MySQL `WHERE` clause. I think I know what the problem is, just not how to fix it.

I have a database with student timetable information and I'm matching this against a table with student information. The student information has been imported into the database from a CSV (utf-8) file, the other information was just inserted into the database with "normal" `INSERT` queries.

The `WHERE` clause is simple and looks like this:

```
WHERE  gpu_timetable.cls_name = 
  (SELECT cls_name FROM gpu_students WHERE std_number = 123441 LIMIT 1)
```

Its matching the cls_name (class name) from the timetable against the class name from the students table. Like I said the data is from different sources but looks to be the same. For example when I remove the SELECT query and use this string ('LV6A') the code works.

The collation on both of the fields is *utf8_general_ci*, I also tried `TRIM()` but no success, the same for replacing the operator `=` with `LIKE`.

Did I do something wrong when importing the student information or is there another function similar to `TRIM()` that can fix this weird problem?

Comment: Why are you using a subselect here?  Why not a JOIN?

Comment: Are you sure is working before the CSV import? Because MySQL does not allow LIMIT in subquery.

Comment: @MikeBrant you are right that I could use a JOIN and that that probably would be a faster way of doing it. 
The problem is just that the match is not working, not with the sub select nor with the `JOIN`.

Comment: @ajreal thanks, I didn't know that `LIMIT` was not allowed in sub select queries.

My query was working before the CSV import, but I was using a different query. Still this match doesn't work or this simplified query should have returned something.

`SELECT *
FROM gpu_timetable INNER JOIN gpu_students 
   ON gpu_timetable.cls_name = gpu_students.cls_name                 
WHERE std_number = 123441`

Answer (score 0):

Your simplified query must be:

```
SELECT * FROM gpu_timetable INNER JOIN gpu_students ON gpu_timetable.cls_name = gpu_students.cls_name WHERE gpu_students.std_number = 123441
```

*Your should always have `tablename.fieldname` while using JOIN queries.*